# Creating a computed Int column in SQL Server from a text column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a new column in an existing SQL Server table that utilizes state abbreviations (an existing column) to recode the states into a number (1-50) for statistical analysis that will be performed after exporting the output.

Assuming that Alabama is AL = 1 and Wyoming is WY = 50, how would I go about doing this for every state?

Comment: Create a table to hold the states and have an ID column.  Then you can join to this table and use the number for whatever you want in your queries.

Comment: I also suggest you make the column in your existing table a `FOREIGN KEY` of the new table, after you have created and populated it, so that that people can't add non-existent states. Also, I hope your column isn't a `text` column; it should be a `char(2)` by the looks of it.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1. Create a lookup table, `STATE_ID` (with values 1..50) and `STATE_ABBREV` ('AL' to 'WY'), then join on this table.
2. Create a large `CASE` statement:

```sql
CASE STATE_ABBR
  WHEN 'AL' THEN 1
  ...
  WHEN 'WY' THEN 50
  ELSE NULL
END AS STATE_ID
```

Using a lookup table is really preferred, as this puts the logic into a single place in case it gets used elsewhere.  Plus, this is really data, and coding it into a view as code is not the right way to go.

Comment: `DEFAULT NULL` is not valid syntax, it should either be `ELSE NULL` or just omitted entirely (since `NULL` is, in fact, the default if no comparison matches). Note that T-SQL has no case *statement* (unlike some languages), this would be a case *expression*. Aside from things being more maintainable in a separate table, a `CASE` expression like this also tends to perform badly since it expands into a huge `OR` internally, the optimizer can't gather statistics on it for join purposes, and it may be recomputed many times.

Comment: You're right; I've been spending too much time with JavaScript :)  Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! I'm just getting into SQL so I'm fairly inexperienced -- I usually just do the stats in SAS so the whole relating tables thing is new for me!

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, if you don't want to use a temporary or lookup table.  Create a list of all states in the alphabetical order, and use the charindex function as shown below

```
create table #temp
( stateCode char(2))
INSERT INTO #temp values ('PA'),('AL'),('NJ'),('MA'),('DC')

select StateCode,charindex(Statecode+'|','AL|PA|NJ|NY|MA|DC|')/3+1 as numb
from #temp
order by numb
```

Note that charindex is slow, but this approach could be adapted to your computed field if you want.

Again, I think a lookup table is a better solution, but if it has to be a computed field, this should work for you

Comment: If you try it you'll see `DC` is assigned a wrong number (since the lookup string didn't terminate with `|`). In fact, any incorrect code will end up getting the number for `AL`, which is probably not desirable. Fixing both issues is easy, but makes the expression even less obvious than it is (`nullif(charindex(Statecode+'|','AL|PA|NJ|NY|MA|DC|'),0)/3+1`). I'm not a fan of `CASE` for this but `CHARINDEX` seems even less appealing, in terms of maintainability.

Comment: Yep, fully agree, I would not want to user CHARINDEX for anything major.  That is why I agreed with the lookup table approach.   However, if they really need a computed field, this is an approach to consider.